# SwiftUI view doesn't update after asynchronous work resolution

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm attempting to update a view based on the result of an async call that takes place in another view. At a high level, I have an object passed to the view doing the work as a `@Binding` and to the reader view as the plain value, and the work view is able to update the object correctly but the updates don't appear in the reader view until you re-navigate to it manually:

[image: Video of problem]

I have to assume I'm going about some part of this in an incorrect way, but I can't tell what the fix is. I've tried making the `Request` type inherit from `ObservableObject` and manually calling `self.objectWillChange.send()` at the end of the HTTP work, but that also didn't change things for me. Similarly marking the `response` property as `@Published` doesn't alter the behavior (tried based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66694643/swiftui-view-does-not-update-after-image-changed-asynchronous))

Any suggestions on how to get these views updating together would be much appreciated.

Below is the sample code the preview above is from:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

// MARK: Backing data -
@Model
class Request {
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    @Transient
    @Published
    var response: ResponseData? = nil
    
    init() {
        self.id = UUID().uuidString
        self.response = nil
    }
}

struct ResponseData {
    var body: Data? = nil
    var response: URLResponse? = nil
    var error: Error? = nil
}

// MARK: App main & views -
@main
struct sampleApp: App {
    var sharedModelContainer: ModelContainer = {
        let schema = Schema([
            Request.self,
        ])
        let modelConfiguration = ModelConfiguration(schema: schema, isStoredInMemoryOnly: false)
        
        do {
            return try ModelContainer(for: schema, configurations: [modelConfiguration])
        } catch {
            fatalError("Could not create ModelContainer: \(error)")
        }
    }()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .modelContainer(sharedModelContainer)
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext
    @Query var allRequests: [Request]
    
    @State var activeRequest: Request? = nil
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView{
            VStack {
                List(allRequests, id: \.self, selection: $activeRequest) { request in
                    Text(request.id)
                }
                Button {
                    modelContext.insert(Request())
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                }
            }
        } content: {
            if activeRequest != nil {
                OperatorView(activeRequest: activeRequest!)
            }
            else {
                Text("Select a request")
            }
        } detail: {
            if activeRequest != nil {
                NeighborView(activeRequest: activeRequest!)
            }
            else {
                Text("No request has been selected")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct OperatorView: View {
    @Bindable var activeRequest: Request
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            Task{
                let url: URL = URL(string: "https://www.google.com/")!
                
                var request = URLRequest(url: url)
                request.httpMethod = "GET"
                
                let session = URLSession(configuration: .ephemeral)
                
                session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
                    guard error == nil else {
                        print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No data")
                        return
                    }
                    
                    activeRequest.response = ResponseData(body: data, response: response, error: error)
                }.resume()
            }
        } label: {
            Text("Do Task")
        }
    }
}

struct NeighborView: View {
    var activeRequest: Request
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Active request is \(activeRequest.id)")
            if activeRequest.response != nil {
                Text("The request completed!")
            }
            else {
                Text("The request hasn't been run yet (or the view hasn't updated)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to base it on the post to which you linked (which I wrote the answer to), you would use an `ObservableObject` and a `@Published` property. If you want to use `Model`, you wouldn't do that, but I'm a bit confused as to why a `Model` would be making a network request and why it would exist if it only has an `id` and a `Transient` property. This seems like you'd be better off just using `@State` and a `task` on your `View` to do the request.

Comment: You could also use the new Observable framework, but if you did that your class would be Observable, not a Model

Comment: @jnpdx I agree the structure of things is a bit weird, but it's more for the example than for the actual code of the destination project. In reality there are a lot more details in that model that I want to keep in SwiftData but I removed them to keep the example from being cluttered. For the sake of completeness though I retried things with the work in a `Task` on the button itself instead of in the object but it doesn't change the update behavior.

Comment: Please include a [mre]

Comment: What about the example above do you believe doesn't meet the criteria of a minimal reproducible example? The code given can be pasted into a brand new xcode project and will reproduce the behavior we're talking about, and it still functions as close my actual project as possible while excluding fields and views which would be unused and do not affect the reproduced behavior.

Comment: My mistake -- my page had not shown me the scroll view and all that was visible was the first model

Comment: `Binding` is for value types `Bindable` is for `Model`

Comment: @loremipsum I'll update the example above to show the more correct `@Bindable` version, but it doesn't have an impact on the behavior

Comment: "I have an object passed to the view doing the work as a @Binding" Where?

Comment: Published won’t work, it needs a whole chain of things to work with SwiftUI. Try making ResponseData Codable, Hashable and Equatable. SwiftUI depends on those protocols to know when things have changed. It might be challenging. Also mixing Task with completion handlers is usually the cause of a leak use pure async/await. Data task is the old way.

Comment: @loremipsum Thank you, yes that was the missing piece. I'll post an answer with the complete solution

Answer (score -1):

Per @loremipsum in the comments above, the missing piece was the `Request` model being a `Hashable` & `ObservableObject`:

[image: Functional solution]

The below example also fixes the mixed `Task`/`dataTask` usage noted in the comments.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

// MARK: Backing data -
@Model
class Request: Hashable, ObservableObject {
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    @Transient
    @Published
    var response: ResponseData? = nil
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
        // And other fields that exist in the non-example object
    }
    
    static func == (lhs: Request, rhs: Request) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    
    init() {
        self.id = UUID().uuidString
        self.response = nil
    }
}

struct ResponseData {
    var body: Data? = nil
    var response: URLResponse? = nil
    var error: Error? = nil
}

// MARK: App main & views -
@main
struct sampleApp: App {
    var sharedModelContainer: ModelContainer = {
        let schema = Schema([
            Request.self,
        ])
        let modelConfiguration = ModelConfiguration(schema: schema, isStoredInMemoryOnly: false)
        
        do {
            return try ModelContainer(for: schema, configurations: [modelConfiguration])
        } catch {
            fatalError("Could not create ModelContainer: \(error)")
        }
    }()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .modelContainer(sharedModelContainer)
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext
    @Query var allRequests: [Request]
    
    @State var activeRequest: Request? = nil
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView{
            VStack {
                List(allRequests, id: \.self, selection: $activeRequest) { request in
                    Text(request.id)
                }
                Button {
                    modelContext.insert(Request())
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                }
            }
        } content: {
            if activeRequest != nil {
                OperatorView(activeRequest: activeRequest!)
            }
            else {
                Text("Select a request")
            }
        } detail: {
            if activeRequest != nil {
                NeighborView(activeRequest: activeRequest!)
            }
            else {
                Text("No request has been selected")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct OperatorView: View {
    @ObservedObject var activeRequest: Request
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            Task{
                let url: URL = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!
    
                var request = URLRequest(url: url)
                request.httpMethod = "GET"
                
                do {
                    let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
                    activeRequest.response = ResponseData(body: data, response: response)
                } catch {
                    activeRequest.response = ResponseData(error: error)
                }
            }
        } label: {
            Text("Do Task")
        }
    }
}

struct NeighborView: View {
    @ObservedObject var activeRequest: Request
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Active request is \(activeRequest.id)")
            if activeRequest.response != nil {
                Text("The request completed!")
            }
            else {
                Text("The request hasn't been run yet (or the view hasn't updated)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mmmm I didn’t say use ObservableObject, Observable which comes with Model replaces ObservableObject. I also didn’t say to override the Model implementations of those protocols, ResponseData needs the protocols.

Comment: To be honest, you should be clear about where things belong to. "Separation of concerns" is a thing. You are trying to mix everything into the view and then get overwhelmed by accidental complexity. Try to define a layer which provides your data and move all that data related stuff to there. Then keep in mind, a view is a "function of state", means just give a view data and the view renders it. Define this state carefully, it models your view. The remaining part is a single, pure _function_ responsible to compute a new state from the current state and events that happen, like responses.

Comment: FWIW, in general, I would not recommend having hashable and equatable exclude properties. I especially would not do so if that is the very property for which you are trying to observe changes.

Answer (score -1):

First, in SwiftUI it's `.task` not `Task { }` - that is required for the lifetime to be correct. Next, you need to move the async code to a common parent `View` and use `.task(id:)` where the `id` is a state that you pass a binding down to all the child Views that you want to start the work from, e.g.

```
struct ParentView: View {
    @State var isRunning = false
    @State var result: Result?
 
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ChildView(isRunning: $isRunning)
            ChildView(isRunning: $isRunning)
            if let result {
                ResultView(result: result)
            }
        }
        .task(id: isRunning) { // usually id is the actual data you want to use in your async work, e.g. a itemID to download the item of, but in this case its a simple bool.
            if !isRunning { return }
            // do async work
            // result = await ...
            isRunning = false
        }
    }
}


struct ChildView: View {
    @Binding var isRunning: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Button(isRunning ? "Stop" : "Start") {
            isRunning.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```

Note, the `.task` is cancelled when the UI described by that `View` disappears so you need to make it high enough in the hierarchy so it will keep running, i.e. you might want to use `.task` on the `NavigationSplitView` because that will never disappear.